# CREATE CONTROLFILE failed ORA-01210: data file header is media corrupt

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am trying to recover a DB beacause I've lost control file. So I try to create a new one:

```
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "MYDB" RESETLOGS ARCHIVELOG
MAXLOGFILES 16
MAXLOGMEMBERS 2
MAXDATAFILES 100
MAXINSTANCES 8
MAXLOGHISTORY 292
DATAFILE
'/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/system.271.1',
'/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/users.291.1',
'/disk2/sysaux/sysaux.272.1'
;
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01503: CREATE CONTROLFILE failed
ORA-01210: data file header is media corrupt
ORA-01110: data file :
'/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/system.271.1'
ORA-01189: file is from a different RESETLOGS than previous files
ORA-01110: data file 9:
'/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/system.271.1'
```

How can i solve this problem? I need those datafiles

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use noresetlogs option?
For which reason are you re-creating or creating this controlfile?